# Should I "duplicate" fields when I use composition?

Tags: java, field, getter

I am using a symbol class (periodic element) which is define as :

```
enum Symbol{
    n(0),
    H(1),
    He(2),
    Li(3),
    Be(4),
    B(5),
    C(6),
    N(7),
    O(8),
    F(9),
    Ne(10),
    //...

    private final int atomicNumber;

    Symbol(int atomicNumber)
    {
         this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
    }

    public int getAtomicNumber() {return atomicNumber;}
```

And I am writing an element class (chemical element) :

```
enum Element {
    Neutron(Symbol.n, "Neutron"),
    Hydrogen(Symbol.H, "Hydrogen"),
    Helium(Symbol.He, "Helium"),
    Lithium(Symbol.Li, "Lithium"),
    Beryllium(Symbol.Be, "Beryllium"),
    Boron(Symbol.B, "Boron"),
    Carbon(Symbol.C, "Carbon"),
    Nitrogen(Symbol.N, "Nitrogen"),
    Oxygen(Symbol.O, "Oxygen"),
    Fluorine(Symbol.F, "Fluorine"),
    Neon(Symbol.Ne, "Neon"),
    //...

    private final Symbol symbol;
    private final String name;

    Element(Symbol symbol, String name)
    {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.name = name;
    }

    public Symbol getSymbol(){return symbol;}
}
```

I want my Element class to give a simple access to `atomicNumber`. I try to prohibit getter chaining as :

```
// Chaining getters
Element.H.getSymbol().getAtomicNumber();
```

**which one of the following solution I should use and why ?**

**Solution 1:**

```
private final Symbol symbol;
private final String name;
private final int atomicNumber; // I added a field to Element

Element(Symbol symbol, String name)
{
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.name = name;  
        this.atomicNumber = symbol.getAtomicNumber();
}
// I implemented the corresponding getter (this.atomicNumber)
public int getAtomicNumber(){return atomicNumber;}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
private final Symbol symbol;
private final String name;

Element(Symbol symbol, String name)
{
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.name = name;
}

// I get atomicNumber from this.symbol
public int getAtomicNumber(){return symbol.getAtomicNumber());}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think, that the convinience of not chaining getters is important, you should use the second approach. duplicating fields is error prone.
You should nevertheless check your basic assumptions - I would argue the atomic number belongs to the element rather than to the symbol; there is a periodic table of elements, not symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will use second approach. For this example, I will bring `atomicNumber` back to the class it belongs. Thank you !

Comment: @lexicore you have to keep more data synchronized. If you change the access to a field or if you have a computed field you must ensure that every change on one field is mirrored in the other field too. This might seem an easy task for a simple class with only final fields (but nevertheless is a task), but classes tend to be changed over time and might be reused etc.. In every place you'd have to keep track of the duplication issue.

Comment: @juwil Both fields are `final`. So, no changes. Nothing to synchronize.